# Installation Book Crossing core depuis git

Tags: software-installation

<sub>Translated from original</sub>

Hello, I would like to install Book Crossing Core on Elementary OS running as a VirtualBox VM, but I'm not sure how to install it.

The instructions can be found here: https://github.com/bookcrossing/bkxng-core

Can anybody help me?

Regards,

---

<sub>Original</sub>

Bonjour, je souhaite installer Book crossing core sur Elementary installé avec virtual box.

Je ne parviens pas à identifier comment l'installer pouvez vous m'aider.

Le lien: https://github.com/bookcrossing/bkxng-core

Cordialement,

Emmanuel

Answer (score 1):

The GitHub repository that you linked to has not been updated in over five years, so there is a good chance that the software will not work for you. However, it looks like a standard Drupal installation with some custom plugins, so you might be able to install it with a normal LAMP stack.

Here's how:

#### Install the Apache Web Server

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Update your sources:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
2. Install Apache:

   ```
   sudo apt install apache2
   ```
3. If you are running UFW, allow Apache through:

   ```
   sudo ufw app list
   ```

   You will see something like this:

   ```
   Available applications:
      Apache
      Apache Full
      Apache Secure
      OpenSSH
   ```
4. Allow Apache to have access:

   ```
   sudo ufw allow in "Apache"
   ```
5. Test Apache is working by visiting http://127.0.0.1 or http://localhost in your browser. You should see a standard Apache page.

#### Install the MySQL Database Server

1. Install MySQL:

   ```
   sudo apt install mysql-server
   ```
2. Configure the database server:

   ```
   sudo mysql_secure_installation
   ```

   You will be asked for a password, and if you want to remove example accounts and databases. Feel free to answer these questions any way you'd like.
3. Test MySQL by connecting and creating a database and account for Book Crossing:

   ```
   sudo mysql
   ```

   If everything is good, you should now be connected to MySQL:

   ```
   mysql> CREATE DATABASE `drupal` DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
   mysql> CREATE USER 'books'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'superSecretPassword!123';
   mysql> GRANT ALL ON `drupal`.* TO 'books'@'localhost';
   mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   ```

   <sub>**Note:** Do not copy the `mysql>` part. That's just to let you know it's a command for MySQL.</sub>
4. Exit from MySQL:

   ```
   mysql> exit;
   ```

#### Install PHP

1. Install PHP and some common packages:

   ```
   sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php php-mysql php-xml php-json php-mbstring php-gd php-devel
   ```
2. Restart Apache:

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```
3. Test PHP is working by creating a simple file in the `/var/www/html` directory:

   ```
   sudo vi /var/www/html/test.php
   ```

   <sub>**Note:** Feel free to use any text editor you prefer.</sub>
   Paste the following code into the new file:

   ```
   <?php phpinfo(); ?>
   ```

   Save the file.
4. Check that PHP works by visiting http://127.0.0.1/test.php or http://localhost/test.php in your browser. You should see a long page describing PHP with all the settings and packages.

#### Install Book Crossing

0. Make sure you're in `/var/www/html`:

   ```
   cd /var/www/html
   ```
1. Download the `.zip` file from GitHub to your `/var/www/html` directory:

   ```
   sudo wget https://github.com/bookcrossing/bkxng-core/archive/refs/heads/master.zip
   ```
2. Unzip the file:

   ```
   sudo unzip master.zip
   ```
3. Change permissions for all files and folders in the `html` directory to ensure Apache can access them all:

   ```
   sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
   ```
4. Start the installation process by visiting http://127.0.0.1/install.php or http://localhost/install.php in your browser.
5. Follow the steps on the screen, remembering to enter the same MySQL account credentials as you created when testing MySQL earlier.

There are a lot of steps, but this is not *too* difficult so long as you go slow and pay attention the first few times you do this.